# SQL-Server - Grant user DBO permission on database

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, permissions

I have a reporting database that I restore every night from a backup of the production database.
When I restore, I need to add a user to the `DBO` role for that database.

I thought this would work:

```
use Restored_Prod
go
exec sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'chris'
go
```

But I get the following error, since that user doesn't exist in the Restored_Prod database:

```
Msg 15410, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_addrolemember, Line 75
User or role 'chris' does not exist in this database.
```

How do I add the user 'chris' to the database to be able to run the `sp_addrolemember` to make him a `DBO` of that database?
Is there a way to add the user permissions using `sp_addrolemember` command from the master db where the user exists?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

User principals must exist in a database before you can grant them permissions.

```
use Restored_Prod
GO

CREATE USER [chris] FROM LOGIN [chris];
exec sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'chris';
GO
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173463.aspx

Comment: That makes sense - I didn't know there was a distinction between login and user.  Thanks

Comment: See [this answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/40845/7611) to a different question where I explain the login/user relationship in a little more detail.